# Azure Point-To-Site VPN subnetting issues

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, azure

I'm currently having some issues with connecting the VPN to my Vnet properly.

The Virtual Network is called **MGS-vnet** with an address space of **10.0.0.0/8**.

It contains 2 subnets:

1. default with an address range of **10.0.0.0/16**
2. GatewaySubnet with an address range of **10.1.0.0/16**

I then have a Virtual Network Gateway, aptly named **VPN**.

Under **MGS-vnet** there is a VM called **MGSServ1** which is connected by a network inteface **mgsserv1261** and assigned the IP address **10.0.0.4**.

The issue is that I can't get the VPN to communicate with the **MGSServ1**, I've attempted with some different netmasks since I noticed that might've been the issue so I changed the address space to **10.0.0.0/8** which is now my current configuration, I believe this would be the correct configuration but that address space means I cannot specify an address range on the **Point-To-Site** that isn't already reserved.

> Failed to save virtual network gateway 'VPN'. Error: The virtual network gateway's VPN client address pool overlaps with the virtual network's address space. The overlapping address space prefixes are 10.0.0.0/8 and 10.1.0.0/24.

Hope you can advise where the issue is in creating this connection between the VPN and the VM.

I've also attempted with creating a **Route Table** between the IP range of **VPN** to the specific VM, I was unable to get that working and not sure if I should proceed with that solution.

**Network Diagram**

[Networking Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqVmE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out that this was a non-issue, if I returned to my previous setup and had the IP addresses seperate, it could still connect.

The reasoning behind this was me testing for a shared drive to see if the connection was there, I also tried to ping the IP which was not sufficient, if I connected through RDP to the internal IP address I could access the VM.

The issue was then port-blocking issues with port 445 since I could not see the shared drives.